# Django password_reset email through app-engine mail api

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to figure out how to get the built-in password_reset view to leverage [appengine's mail api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/sending-mail-with-mail-api) instead. Is this possible?

I've got several of my own custom views leveraging appengine's mail api just fine, but the default password_reset view I'm guessing tries to use regular send_mail and expects valid smtp settings. I'd prefer not to put my `google user/pass` in `local_settings.py`. Is it possible to override `send_mail` in `password_reset`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've answered my own question (classic). You can override the form used for password_reset, so I'll just use the [default form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L242) as a base and change to leverage appengine mail api instead.

[Update]
This confirmed worked for me. I added a MyPasswordResetForm in forms.py and copy/paste from the default PasswordReset form. Then I just commented the lines that used EmailMultiAlternatives and used appengine's EmailMessage instead. Then I updated my urls.py for password_reset to include 'password_reset_form': MyPasswordResetForm. Now the password_reset view points to my custom form, which uses appengines mail api instead.

Appengine can now send emails directly for password_reset.